# Custom legend labels in my rechart chart

Tags: recharts

I have a pretty straight forward data array for my **recharts** component :

```
{name: '12.1.2011', series1: 4000, series2: 2400, series3: 2400},
{name: '12.2.2011', series1: 3000, series2: 1398, series3: 2210},
{name: '12.3.2011', series1: 2000, series2: 9800, series3: 2290}
```

I would like to have labels for the series values in my Legend. Instead of the chart showing me the different colors for "series1", "series2", and "series3".

Of course I could set the actual values I want to use for my legend in the JSON already but this just doesn't look right. Eg :

```
{name: '12.1.2011', 'My nice long descriptive text': 4000, 'Some other text': 2400, 'Some other descriptive text': 2400},
{name: '12.2.2011', 'My nice long descriptive text': 3000, 'Some other text': 1398, 'Some other descriptive text: 2210},
{name: '12.3.2011', 'My nice long descriptive text': 2000, 'Some other text': 9800, 'Some other descriptive text: 2290}
```

I need to map my series level to a descriptive label.

I have looked at **content** in Legend : http://recharts.org/#/en-US/api/Legend, but that seems more concerned with completely rewriting the Legend Component.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 52):

In your `Line`, `Bar` and `Area` add a `name` attribute.

Example:

```
<Line name="# Apples" type="monotone" dataKey="series1" stroke="#FF0000" />
<Line name="# Bananas" type="monotone" dataKey="series2" stroke="#FFFF00" />
<Line name="# Grapes" type="monotone" dataKey="series3" stroke="#FF00FF" />
```

The legend will pick this up automatically:

http://recharts.org/en-US/api/Legend

> By default, the content of legend is generated by the name of Line,
>   Bar, Area, etc. When no name has been setted, dataKey will be used to
>   generate legend content alternatively.

Comment: what about pie charts?

Answer (score 14):

If you're looking to get this working on a `<Pie />` you can override the `<Legend />` `payload`. Please see the following example;

```
<Legend
  payload={
    data.map(
      (item, index) => ({
        id: item.name,
        type: "square",
        value: `${item.name} (${item.value}%)`,
        color: colors[index % colors.length]
      })
    )
  }
/>
```

http://recharts.org/en-US/api/Legend#payload

Comment: It is useful but it seems to ruin colors in the legend items

Answer (score 4):

For custom legend, use content props, Ref: https://recharts.org/en-US/api/Legend#content

```
const renderLegend = (props) => {
  const { payload } = props;

  return (
    <ul>
      {
        payload.map((entry, index) => (
          <li key={`item-${index}`}>{entry.value}</li>
        ))
      }
    </ul>
  );
}
<Legend content={renderLegend} />
```

Comment: OP explicitly referenced the content option and rejected that.

Answer (score 0):

just add "name" attr to  or  or .... like:

```
<Line {...props} name="volume"/>
```